How to get difference between 2 TimeOfDay in flutter?
I want to get the duration of difference between 2 times current time and future time in 24 format and I want to store the duration in Duration class. i.e. currentTime = 13:30:20, futureTime = 16:30:10. Now I want to get its diffenrence duration = 03:00:10 and running the timer up to 16:30:10.
for more clearity ...
setDurationForTimes(DateTime time) {
    String x = DateFormat('hh:mm').format(time);
    TimeOfDay _startTime = TimeOfDay(
        hour: int.parse(x.split(":")[0]), minute: int.parse(x.split(":")[1]));
    var y = TimeOfDay(hour: _startTime.hour, minute: _startTime.minute);
    prayerTimeDuration = Duration(
      hours: _startTime.hour,
      minutes: _startTime.minute,
    );
    return y;
  }


You can use Intl package for this.
First Import Intl Package
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Then use it by creating a custom format.
var format = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); //creating custom format.

DateTime currentTime = format.parse("13:30:20");
DateTime futureTime = format.parse("16:30:10");
Duration timeDifference = futureTime.difference(currentTime); // calculates time difference.
print("${timeDifference}"); //prints calculated time difference.


I also worked with this but I want the current time it means I want DateTime.now(). I want the converted time like 13:30:20. I home we got an answer. thank you.

And also removing the milliseconds 2:59:44.994861. I want just HH:mm:ss or HH:mm.

yes you can achieve this by replacing current time with this.
DateTime currentTime = format.parse("${DateTime.now().hour}:${DateTime.now().minute}:${DateTime.now().second}");
